# Creating google calendar like calendar ui and functionality in ionic 2

Tags: angular, calendar, ionic2

I started working on ionic 2 just a week ago. So far it has been smooth sailing . But now i am stuck. I have to provide a calendar interface to the user to book a time slot. Can anyone help me out in carrying out this task? I just need some advice on how to start . I am completely blank right now. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule

Comment: Do you want a date picker or  calendar?

Comment: @rinukkusu exactly what i need. but i am not sure how to make it work. thanks anyways

Comment: @AngJobs not datepicker. i want a scheduling interface. But thanks for trying

Comment: @ShreelakshmiGangadhar how did it go? What did you end up doing/using?

Comment: @Mukus 

https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar

Answer (score -2):

Check the newly introduced Datepicker in the Ionic blog:
http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-fixing-date-inputs-for-the-mobile-web/

and here in the components:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#datetime

Comment: Datepickers are a poor solution for selecting dates that are not birthdays.  Also, this answer does not expose a calendar interface.